# Showing Google Drive Image on React Native

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api

I'm building a React Native App and am trying to show a list of brands with their corresponding images. The images (700+) are all in a Google Drive Folder.

I was using a no-code tool before where I could just paste the image link and it would render, but it's not working on React Native.

Any idea on how this could be done?

Comment: Google drive is NOT a file hosting service,  your going to be blocked doing this.  Your only going to be able to show a couple of files before it locks you down.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1- go to drive and get the public link of the photo ex: https://drive.google.com/file/d/176kEvQYm2MPJ80UDxRWjiFq0OK1OkhYc/view?usp=sharing

2- go to this website https://www.labnol.org/embed/google/drive/ and get the embed link

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

const imageUrl = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/AITFw-w28cTZxDoEn727SvoA_VrO7btaWSb2h-YzleV4QvQfNkPqFoJG1R4Qw_Gwj_ttAdmW9vE8qxQcEc3d8Z3JoYIiYPsjXw=s1600"

const MyComponent=()=> {
    return (
       <Image
        source={{ uri: testPhotoUri }}
        className="w-14 h-14 rounded-full mr-2"
       />
    );
};
```

You should see the image like this:

[image]

ps: you should set the height and width of the image, in my case is. h-14 and w-14 because I'm using tailwindCss. you can do the same like this:

```
  <Image
   style={{ height: 56, width: 56, borderRadius: 28 }}
   source={{ uri: imageUrl }}
   className="w-14 h-14 rounded-full mr-2"
  />
```